# How to Configure AutoLayout for UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

I have a UIView in my iOS app that holds a graph. I have fully constrained the UIView in Interface Builder but yet when I view the page on my iPhone 6 the graph is a nice large size but yet when viewed on an iPhone 4s, the view appears much shorter to the point where it's uncomfortable to look at.

The constraints are as follows:
[image]

As viewed on an iPhone 4s:
[image]

As viewed on an iPhone 6:[image]

How can I adjust the constraints so that the iPhone 4s UIView has similar proportions to that of the iPhone 6?

Comment: Is the 4S version always shorter? Do you see any warnings in the console? Are there any other constraints?

Comment: The 4S version is always shorter. The data is generated during an app session so they both display different data points however the 4S version doesn't budge no matter what data it holds.

Comment: Since you have a constraint setting the graph's height to 150 points you should get a log statement in the console telling you that the constraint is breaking if the height on the device is less than that. Also, check the priority on that constraint, it's possible that it's getting clobbered by a higher priority constraint somewhere else.

Comment: It has a priority of 1000 but I'll look for the log

Comment: There isn't any log and when I enter the View Hierarchy it doesn't appear that the UIView extends under any other elements.

Comment: Try pausing in the debugger and typing the following command: `po [[[UIApplication sharedApplication]keyWindow]recursiveDescription]`. It should show you the frames for all the views that are on screen.

Comment: When I enter that I just get: error: use of undeclared identifier 'UIApplication'
error: 1 errors parsing expression. Wouldn't that just give me the same information as the View Hierarchy?

Comment: Do you have a height constraint on the table rows below the graph? As stated above, look in the console for a broken constraint at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be some conflict in the constraints in 4S.
For this UIView, if the superview is fixed in terms of size, then only 2 of the following constraints need to be set.

- align top to superview
- align bottom to superview
- height equals 150

Or if the superview is not fixed in size, then the superview constraints might have conflict with the tableview down below. try to set the tableview height using percentage, not the fix number?

Comment: Wow, so it turns out I really screwed up. The constraints I posted were for the wrong view. Upon realizing this and taking a look at the right view, I had a fixed constraint from the bottom of the graph to the bottom layout that was pushing things up. Stupid mistake but thanks everyone for taking the time to help!